# Setting object property to Array Literal throwing error

Tags: javascript

I have very simple line in js,

```
var a = new {
          aa: []
       }
```

But this line throwing error in js.

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Any reason why?

Comment: `{ aa: [] }` is not a function, so it can't be used as a constructor with `new`.

Comment: @apsillers, it's a key and its value is array. For example, {aa: 'a'} works. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: It's not a function, so it's not a sensible constructor to use with `new`. You use `new` with a function that constructs an object. `new { aa: 'a' }` does not work, and it produces an identical error.

Comment: @apsillers, what do you mean by not a function.

Comment: `{ key: expression }` is so-called 'object literal' notation. It's most often used when you just need to store some data/methods as a group, without using any class/object-related features (like inheritance). `new`, on the contrary, is to be used with a constructor functions. Don't mix those.

Comment: See MDN's [examples on how to use `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Examples). The syntax is `new Thing()` (where `Thing` is some constructor).

Comment: @raina77ow, I think there should definitively a reason to not use object literal with constructor.

Comment: Constructor in JavaScript is a _function_. Tell me, how it's related to object literal?

Comment: There is a reason. The reason is: you only use the `new` operator with constructor functions, and you can't express a function as an object literal. Therefore, you can't use `new` with object literals. According to [ECMAScript 11.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2), the object of a `new` operator must implement a `[[Construct]]` internal property, which is only implemented by functions (and sometimes special browser-supplied host objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) is used to instantiate an object using a constructor (which is a function, hence your error message).

In your case simply use

```
var a = {
      aa: []
}
```

Some references :

- [Values, variables and literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)
- [types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: Means object literals are not allowed

Comment: @user960567 Object literals are certainly *allowed* -- that's exactly what this solution uses. Non-function objects simply aren't valid operands for `new`.

Comment: What do you mean by non-functions?

Comment: @user960567 By "non-function object" I mean any object that is not a function. I was simply saying that `new` expects a function, and you were giving it something other than a function.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the keyword 'new', just use -

```
var a = {
    aa: []
}
```

Comment: Oh Good. But why we cannot use it with new keyword any reason?

Answer (score 1):

Other options:

```
var a = new Object();
a.aa = [];
```

or

```
var a = function(aa) {
  this.aa = aa;
}

var newA = new a([]);
```

U gotta love javascript :)